# Getting an error 'Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square'. What does this mean, and how to resolve it?

Tags: python, scipy, newtons-method

Here's my code:

```
def obj_function(x):
    val= 8*(x[0]**4) + 3*(x[1]**2)- 6*x[0]*x[1] + 2*x[1]
    return np.asmatrix(val)

def obj_function_prime(x):
    val=[32*(x[0]**3)-6*x[1], 6*x[1]-6*x[0]+2]
    return np.asmatrix(val)

def hess_obj_function(x):
    a= 96*(x[0]**2)
    b= -6
    c= -6
    d=  6
    val=[[a,b], [c,d]]
    return np.asmatrix(val)

tol= 10**(-6)
mu= 0.2
xk= np.asmatrix([1,1])
xold= np.asmatrix([0,0])

while np.linalg.norm(obj_function_prime(xk))> tol:
    xold=xk
    alpha=1.0
    while obj_function(xk- alpha*obj_function_prime(xk))> (obj_function(xk)- mu*alpha*np.dot(obj_function_prime(xk), obj_function(xk))):
        alpha=0.5* alpha
    xk= xk-alpha*obj_function_prime(xk)
    
print(" The minimum of the function occurs at", xk)
```

And this gives me error:

```
*
```

> LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>  in 
> 20 xold= np.matrix([0,0])
> 21
> ---> 22 while np.linalg.norm(obj_function_prime(xk))> tol:
> 23     xold=xk
> 24     alpha=1.0
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-3-c0704e734bdd> in obj_function_prime(x)
>       4 
>       5 def obj_function_prime(x):
> ----> 6     val=[32*(x[0]**3)-6*x[1], 6*x[1]-6*x[0]+2]
>       7     return np.matrix(val)
>       8 
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py in __pow__(self, other)
>     231 
>     232     def __pow__(self, other):
> --> 233         return matrix_power(self, other)
>     234 
>     235     def __ipow__(self, other):
>
> <__array_function__ internals> in matrix_power(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in matrix_power(a, n)
>     620     a = asanyarray(a)
>     621     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
> --> 622     _assert_stacked_square(a)
>     623 
>     624     try:
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _assert_stacked_square(*arrays)
>     211         m, n = a.shape[-2:]
>     212         if m != n:
> --> 213             raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
>     214 
>     215 def _assert_finite(*arrays):
>
> LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
> ```

- 

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it? How do I convert a matrix to a square one, when it is not defined that way?

Comment: It means that the last two dimensions must be the same. A full traceback could help identify exactly where the problem is. Also, I'd suggest getting rid of the `asmatrix` calls. Try to make this work with regular numpy arrays (they can be 2d like np.matrix).

Comment: @hpaulj I have edited the question and added the stack trace. Please check, thanks!

Comment: What is `x[0]**3` supposed to be doing?  What do you think `x[0]` is (shape, type, dtype?).  Does that match with what it really is?

Answer (score -1):

Using `np.matrix` is causing problems.

Lets make a small matrix:

```
In [273]: x = np.asmatrix([0,0])
In [274]: x
Out[274]: matrix([[0, 0]])
```

note that when you index it, it doesn't change.  It selects the first 'row', but being `np.matrix` is still 2d.

```
In [275]: x[0]
Out[275]: matrix([[0, 0]])
```

And `**` of `np.matrix` is matrix square, effectively `x@x`.

```
In [276]: x[0]**2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-276-3908b7334115>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0]**2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 231, in __pow__
    return matrix_power(self, other)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in matrix_power
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 621, in matrix_power
    _assert_stacked_square(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 204, in _assert_stacked_square
    raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')
LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

I'm not going try to figure out what you are trying to do, but clearly using `asmatrix` is not the way to go - at least not without understanding how such an array behaves.